# How to make a container expandable horizontally after overflowing?

Tags: html, css, containers, width

I want to create a container that will be filled with text. The text is supposed to first fill the container vertically AND THEN (if needed) expand horizontally: [container_diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipTJI.png)

Like in the picture - container has a fixed height that I don't ever want to change. Then when it starts overflowing I need the container to expand horizontally and I have no idea how to do it.

Among other things I tried using

```
width: min-content
```

but it doesn't expand (https://jsfiddle.net/t8dLo51b/81/).

```
width: fit-content
```

but it doesn't let the text fill the container vertically at first (https://jsfiddle.net/t8dLo51b/83/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#a {
  display: flex;

}

p {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

The first style is applied to an element with the ID `a`. It sets this element to use the `display: flex` property, which means it will be displayed as a flexible container.

The second style is applied to all `p` elements (paragraphs) on the page. It sets these elements to use the `display: flex` property along with other styles such as padding, automatic width, a solid black border of 1 pixel, automatic height, and word break to prevent the content from overflowing the width of the element.